# How to restrict my rest api to be used by only the referrer URLs with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, curl

I have a rest api in nodejs and would restrict the access only from particular URLS?

My node.js code:

```
var express=require("express");
var app=express();
var auth = require('basic-auth');

appStart.use(function(req, res, next) {

    console.log(req.get('origin'));
    console.log(requestIp.getClientIp(req));
    console.log(req.ip);

    //check the api key username e password
    var authentication=auth(req);
    if(authentication.name!="apiTokenUsername" || authentication.pass!="apiTokenPassword") res.status(400).send("Api key Username or password incorrect!");

    //check if the ip of request is authorized
    if(req.ip=="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx") return next();

    //check if the origin of request is authorized
    if(req.get('origin') == "www.acceptedUrl.com") return next();

    //if ip isn't "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" or origin isn't "www.acceptedUrl.com"
    res.status(400).send("You are not authorized!");
});

app.get("*",function(req,res){
    res.send("Hello world!);
});
```

**CONSIDERATION**:
1) i can get the ip of the request (req.ip or requestIp.getClientIp(req)) , it's good and work fine!
2) i can read the origin of the request (req.get('origin')) , it's good and work fine! but i found a problem.

**PROBLEM**:
I found that with POSTMAN(https://www.getpostman.com/) or with curl in my mac console i can force a "Origin" in html request header. Example:

```
curl -X GET https://myGateway -H 'origin: www.acceptedUrl.com'
```

So in my node.js code i found that:

```
console.log(req.get('origin')); //--> I found www.acceptedUrl.com
```

**QUESTION**:
There is an alternative and safe way to get the origin of a request?

Comment: Do you have access to the client side code, that issues the requests?

Comment: the problem isn't in the client side code, you can use the api rest from a simple curl request. my problem is how intercept correctly the origin of the request in server side code. thanks

Comment: Yes I understand your problem and I asked about your client code to think about a solution if you have the full control on the part which generates API requests. To my mind it's not possible to correctly guarantee the origin of the request.

Comment: There's no way to guarantee it. You can check it but users can easily modify it or add it by hand.

Comment: Maybe your question is not as clear but just to add that you should simply extract this origin validation into a  separate middleware and then use it in the routes you want protected